# SFDX Lightning Page Deployment Issues Property 'itemInstances' not valid in version 47.0

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

I trying to deploy my package while validating changes salesforce given this error "**Lightning Page Property 'itemInstances' not valid in version 47.0**" do you guys have any insight for these king of errors.
Please share if you got any solution for these.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'itemInstances' and 'processOrder' not valid in version 48.0 error when deploying in Production, even though Production is 49.0](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319174/property-iteminstances-and-processorder-not-valid-in-version-48-0-error-when)

Comment: More related questions- [How can I change the version of a Flexipage through SFDX?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318589/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-a-flexipage-through-sfdx), [Property 'componentInstances' not valid](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317274/property-componentinstances-not-valid-in-version-49-0-but-package-xml-is-versi/317293) and [Metadata Deploy and Push fails on Flexipage componentInstances](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305221/metadata-deploy-and-push-fails-on-flexipage-componentinstances-in-api-49-summer/305222)

Comment: As per documentation, itemInstances is available in API 49.0 or later (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm)

Comment: @Vinay That would be good as an answer, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Metadata API to deploy, you need to update your package.xml to indicate version 49.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 
   your types here...

   <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: I try this but still got the same error, just for a **fix** I used <version>46.0</version> in package XML file.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) itemInstances is available in API 49.0 or later.  Try using 49 version.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>New Opportunity Page</fullName>
    <types>
      -------
      -------
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

Thanks,

Comment: I try this but still got the same error